# CKEditor disable HTML transformation

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, ckeditor

I've got a problem with CKEditor. Especially the br- and img-Tags are transformed to not be valid.
In the source-view I see 
 and  but when I inspect the rte-source the slashes are gone as well as when submitting the form.
Can someone tell me where I can disable this or enable XHTML-conformity? The embedding page is XHTML.

Thank to any hints, ideas or solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem describe above:

This wasn't a problem of CKEditor. I did use jQuery's html-method that relies on the DOM innerHTML property to get CKEditors contents. This property seems to be unable to handle XHTML at all (tested in FF and Chrome).
You need to replace all slashes manually.